# Postgresql Subtracting two columns data and pass that value to next row

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have two columns 'opening balance' and 'issue', 'balance' is 'opening balance' - 'issue'

Table I have

[image]

I need to pass the subtracted 'balance' to pass to next row and so on

Expected result

[image]

Is there any solution ?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name or as a CTE expression

Answer (score 1):

You are solving a variant of "running totals" problem. What is weird on your question is there is no criterion of row ordering - you should have some id or usually timestamp in your data to specify logic order of transactions.

You can solve problem using window functions, for example:

```
with t (order_criterion, opening,issue) as (values
  (1,1200,6),
  (2,1200,10),
  (3,1200,8),
  (4,1200,9)
)
select opening - coalesce(sum(issue) over (order by order_criterion rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0) as opening
     , issue
     , opening - sum(issue) over (order by order_criterion) as closing
from t
```

or

```
with t (order_criterion, opening,issue) as (values
  (1,1200,6),
  (2,1200,10),
  (3,1200,8),
  (4,1200,9)
), i as (
  select order_criterion
       , opening
       , issue
       , opening - sum(issue) over (order by order_criterion) as closing
  from t
)
select coalesce(lag(closing) over (order by order_criterion), opening) as opening
     , issue
     , closing
from i
```

See db fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=53705b0d971deb9395df2091fba0857e